# Possibility of constructing an orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, block-matrices

I have a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, and for each column $j$ of $A$, $\sum_{i}(A[i,j])^2 = 1$ holds. (i.e. sums of squares of each column adds to $1$.)

I want to build a new $2n \times 2n$ matrix that needs to be orthogonal.

$$ M = \left[\begin{array}{c|c} A & C\\ \hline B & D\end{array}\right] $$

Moreover, $C$ must be a "$0$" matrix (i.e., all entities are $0$).

*Size being $2n$ is not strictly necessary. Building a larger $M$ like $(3n+3) \times (3n+3)$ etc. is also acceptable, as long as all entities on the right side of $A$ is zero.*

What I am trying to achive is, to show that such an $M$ exists so I can use it in the remaining part of my proof.

I can build $M$'s for specific cases but I stuck at figuring a generic algorithm or proving such an $M$ exists for generic case.

Any help appreciated. Thank you

EDIT: $A$ is not necessarily orthogonal. What I am trying to achieve is to construct an orthogonal matrix only by changing the values of $B$ and $D$.

---

**Motivation**

I am writing a computer science paper. For the paper, I am trying to convert a probabilistic finite automaton (PFA) to a [quantum finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_finite_automaton) (QFA). One of the steps of this process requires that I construct the matrix $M$ with the aforementioned properties.

Comment: Why not impose that the northeast corner of $M$ be zero instead of presenting it as possibly nonzero and then saying it's zero?

Comment: The columns having unit Euclidean norm can be rephrased by $A^\top A$ has $1$s on its main diagonal.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Initially I wrote "0" instead of "C", but it was not initially apparent visually so I decided to mention it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D=I, C = \mathbb{0}$. Then every column vector has norm $1$. Use dot product of column vectors and $B = C =0$ to show that any two column vectors $v_i, v_j (1\le i\le n, n+1 \le j \le 2n)$ are orthogonal.

Comment: It seems you assume the columns of $A$ are orthgonal. I did not read this anywhere in OP's question.

Comment: You are right. Perhaps first I should make $v_i, v_j (1\le i, j\le n)$ orthogonal.

Comment: @KurtG. is right. $A$ is not necessarily orthogonal. I edited the question to clearify

Answer (score 1):

***Too long for a comment***

If $A$ is orthogonal the trivial solution by user ***sz*** applies: $D=I,B=C=0$.
When $A$ is not orthogonal and you require that $C$ must be zero I have doubts that $D$ exists.

- The $n$ columns of $D$ must be orthogonal (since $C=0$).
- Also: Each of the $n$ columns of $D$ must be orthogonal to every column of $B$. Since the columns of $D$ span $\mathbb R^n$ every column of $B$ must be zero.

This implies that $A$ must be orthgonal but we assumed it is not.

What exactly do you mean by "a larger $M$ like $(3n+3)\times (3n+3)$ is also accepetable" ?

Comment: I also suspected that such a solution could be impossible. In that case, we can consider the case where $M=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  A&B&C\\
\hline
  D&E&F\\
\hline
  G&H&I
\end{array}
\right]$ and $B = C = 0$, and all $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I$ are $n \times n$ matrices. In this case, the problem becomes modifiying matrices $D - I$ to make $M$ orthogonal. At the end, what I need to find is a matrix $M$ which has the upper left side equal to $A$, right side of $A$ is zero and $M$ is orthogonal. Size really does not matter much.

Comment: And ? $C=0$ ? What about the others ?